# How to get rid of variations with unspecified attributes

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, tax-query

Some of my products have these weird variations with unspecified attributes (I am using Size and Color in my store). It looks like this:

[image]

So, if you would purchase a 85 B, Black variation of the product (ID 111224), in reality the order would contain the  variation with unspecified attributes (ID 112392), because it is higher. It is a huge problem because those unspecified variations contain wrong SKUs and additional data.

I am using WP All Import for importing and updating products, I'm suspecting the plugin (or my settings) for this mess and I will look at it. However I have thousands of products in the store and deleting them manually is out of the question. Is there a way to delete variations that has at least one unspecified variation programatically?

I've tried to query such product variations using this tax_query:

```
'tax_query' = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'pa_size',
        'terms'            => array(''),
        'field'            => 'slug',
        'operator'         => 'IN',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy'         => 'pa_color',
        'terms'            => array(''),
        'field'            => 'slug',
        'operator'         => 'IN',
    ),
);
```

But the query doesn't return anything. It doesn't work when I try to pass empty string as a value inside 'term' array. I've also tried the '=' operator and empty string (not an array) as a value.

By the way, I've checked if those empty attributes really are empty strings and yes, they are. This code:

```
$product = wc_get_product(112392);
$atts = $product->get_attributes();
    
foreach($atts as $att) {
    echo gettype($att) . ' : ' . $att .  '<br>';
}
```

outputs this:

```
string : 
string :
```

While for correct variations (e.g. 111224) it outputs:

```
string : 85-b
string : black
```

Any idea how could I get rid of them?
I could just query all products variations, loop through them and delete all empty ones. Maybe repeat it couple of times (based on execution time) but it doesn't seem like a good solution, it is very performance expensive - the same problem might appear in the future as well and I would like a quick solution that would only query broken variations.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to write an SQL query that would get all product variation IDs that **do not have both size and color** set up (not present in the wp_postmeta table). After that I just need to loop through these IDs and delete those variations using `wp_delete_post`. This is the query:

```
SELECT p.ID 
FROM wp_posts p 
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta pm 
ON p.ID = pm.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type = 'product_variation' 
AND (pm.post_id NOT IN (SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'attribute_pa_size' OR meta_key = 'attribute_pa_color')) 
GROUP BY ID
```

Works well for my case. I was originaly asking about variations that has *at least one* attribute unspecified, but turned out that wouldn't be the solution, I had to look for variations with boths attributes empty.